# Developer certificates not installing properly in Keychains iOS 8

Tags: ios8, keychain, xcode6.1

I have the developer certificates and provisions.I am using this certificates for generate the IPA.
But in build settings certificates not accessing.I think that certificate not installed correctly.How to install the certificates in Keychains.
Please give the suggestion

[image]

Comment: Please differentiate Development Certificate and Distribution Certificate. They are different.

Comment: Thanks for giving the reply.  But I installed developer certificates too.I'm getting provisioning fine in build settings but I cannot getting in the code signing identity,how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Ravi,

Thats mean that your development certificated did't created in your machine. for the same you require .P12 file who create this developer certificate.

- Open the Keychain Access application (in the Applications/Utilities
  folder).
- If you have not already added the certificate to Keychain, select
  File > Import. Then navigate to the certificate file (the .cer file) 
  you obtained from Apple.
- Select the Keys category in Keychain Access.
- Select the private key associated with your iPhone Development
  Certificate.
- The private key is identified by the iPhone Developer: 
   public certificate that is paired with it.
- Select File > Export Items.
- Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file
  format.
- You will be prompted to create a password that is used when you
  attempt to import this key on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

To distribute IPA via Ad Hoc Distribution, follow the steps below:

1. Register Bundle ID (App ID) in [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action) > Identifiers
2. Make sure your **Distribution Certificate** has private key stored in Keychain Access (if not, generate a new one at Apple Developer Portal > Certificate > Distribution Certificate) and it is not revoked or expired
3. Generate a Provisioning Profile in Apple Developer Portal > Provisioning Profiles, with target device (if not, register the device's UDID at Apple Developer Portal > Devices first, then repeat Step 3) and the App ID. Assign a human-readable name for the Provisioning Profile
4. Download the Provisioning Profile to your computer, drag to Xcode
5. Select the newly created Provisioning Profile in Xcode > Project Settings > Build Settings > Provisioning Profile
6. Archive the Project in Xcode
7. Click Export in Organizer
8. Save the IPA

or

let Xcode 6+ handle Step 1 to 4 for you by pressing "Fix Issue" in Project Settings after you selected the Team.